# Center Google Sign-in button text (iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, google-signin, gidsignin

I've added to my iOS project a Google login with Firebase but the button (`GIDSignInButton`) text is not centred, and I want to center it (`Sign-in with Google`).

Comment: I digged a lot and finally concluded that you cant change UI created by google unless you opt for a Custom Button for  google login.

Answer (score 0):

yes, we can't change the layout for the google Sign in but that is possible in Android. Might it be available in the near future.

Comment: Please consider posting your answer as a coment

Answer (score 0):

```
var providers = [FUIAuthProvider]()
let googleAuthProvider = FUIGoogleAuth(
                         authUI: authUI, scopes: [ 
                                         kGoogleGamesScope,
                                         kGooglePlusMeScope, 
                                         kGoogleUserInfoEmailScope,
                                         kGoogleUserInfoProfileScope
                                        ] 
                          )
googleAuthProvider.buttonAlignment = .center
```